# Order preserving bijection from a countable subset of R to a subset of N

Tags: real-analysis

Let A be a countable subset of $\Bbb R$ which is well-ordered with respect
to the usual ordering on $\Bbb R$ (where ‘well-ordered’ means that every
nonempty subset has a minimum element in it). Then A has an order
preserving bijection with a subset of $\Bbb N$.

It is given that the above statement is **FALSE**.

But I think it is true. The following is my reasoning.

If A is empty then the statement is true. Because I can give a order preserving bijection from empty set to empty set.

Let A be a non empty set. Since A is well ordered I can arrange the elements of A as $ \{x_1, x_2,x_3,....,x_n\} $ in such a way that $x_1<x_2<....<x_n.$ . So I can give a bijective function $f$ from {1,2,3,...n} to $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ defined by $f(i)=x_i$ which is order preserving.

Similarly I can do it for infinite set too.
Somehow I am not satisfied with my reasoning for the empty set. I want to know
whether the given statement is true or false. If it is false why?

Comment: The sentence beginning "Since $A$ is well ordered$\ldots$" is false! See @Hagen von Eitzen's answer for examples of well-ordered sets where it fails. You might like to think on why your intuition is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try $$A=\{-\tfrac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}\cup \{42\}$$
which is an inifnite well-ordered set with a largest element - a property $\Bbb N$ does not have.
Or even try
$$A=\{k-\tfrac1n\mid n,k\in\Bbb N\}$$
(and there are still weirder countable well-ordered subsets of $\Bbb R$)

Comment: What about my reasoning for the empty set. Whether it's true?

Comment: @CloudJR There is no problem with the empty set. Why are you asking about the empty set, when Hagen von  Eitzen's answer shows that your reasoning is erroneous in the infinite case? There are lots of infinite well-ordered subsets of $\mathbb R$ which **do not** admit an order-preserving bijection to a subset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I asked that to know whether I'm correct or not

Answer (score 1):

The statement is False. To prove that, we just need to provide an example of well-ordered subset of R that doesn't have order-preserving bijection with a subset of N.

Any set A of this type $((-1/(n)^k)UL)$
where $n$ and $k$
belong to $N$
and $L$ is any proper subset of $(0UN)$ except empty set.
This is generalization of the answer above. Awesome example which I didn't see clearly before & I thought was (-n) (because I got a test tomorrow and I'm maxed out).

Also any set A of type $0U1/(n)^k$ where $n$ and $k$ belong to $N$.

Both of the sets have an infimum which makes them well-ordered and they are countable subsets of R. But also, they've a supremum, a property which N does not have.

Why this works is because in order-preserving bijection
$x1<x2$  implies
$f(x1)<f(x2)$
And so if a certain countably infinite set has a supremum and has an order-preserving bijection with $N$, then it would imply $N$ also has a supremum, which is a contradiction.